# Print Specific Line In Lex

Tags: yacc, flex-lexer, lex

I want to print only the lines that begin with the word "Hello"

How can I do it?

i.e

Word----------Print
Hello World (YES)

World Hello (NO)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^"Hello".*$      printf("%s\n", yytext);
```

`^` beggining of line